# Deleting from unknown ListBoxes ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a Window with multiple ListBoxes, each ListBox uses the same KeyDown event to determine if delete was pressed for a highlighted entry. What i need to obtain is a reference to the ListBox selected bound source so i can delete the selected value from it, I can see the object with:

var sourceObject = box.ItemsSource;

this simply returns an IEnumerable list of the items bound to the ListBox.

How can i obtain the bound source Property (reference) so i can remove an underlying value?

Here's the xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listTest1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllTest1Values}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="341,390,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" KeyDown="ListBox_KeyDown">

<ListBox x:Name="listTest2" ItemsSource="{Binding AllTest2Values}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="341,390,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" KeyDown="ListBox_KeyDown">

<ListBox x:Name="listTest3" ItemsSource="{Binding AllTest3Values}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="341,390,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" KeyDown="ListBox_KeyDown">
```

As you can see the Event is always the same, but the binding is different. That's why I need to find a way to obtain a reference to the binding within the 'ListBox_KeyDown' event handler.

Comment: I would be helpful to see the part of your code that sets the "bound source" for a listbox object. For WPF, this can be done in many different ways so in some respects it would be difficult to figure out what would work for you. Can you show that code?

Comment: Thanks, i updated the question.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `wcf`, please fix your tags. Each list box should have their own event handler, so the reference you're looking for is simply the `sender` object. But please don't use this reference to delete anything directly from `ItemsSource`, use proper MVVM instead.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, changed the c to an p. I would love be to use proper MVVM but at the moment I'm transitioning from winforms so I'm hybridising here. The sender is the ListBox, what I need here is a reference to the binding Property for the ListBox. I need to reference the original OberservableCollection<string> bound to the ListBox, I just don't know what they ListBox is until the event triggers so at that point I need to obtain the reference to the actual ItemsSource.

Comment: Trying to emulate Winforms in WPF is a sure recipe for disaster. Your original `ObservableCollection<string>` is in your view model, so you have a reference to it readily available.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'll want the data context.

```
// {Event} needs to be replaced with your event name, such as Click
// {BindingClass} need to be replaced with the name of your binding class, such as ListBoxItems

private void ListBox_{Event}(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var listbox = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var dataContext = ({BindingClass})listbox.DataContext;
}
```

Above, your event handler would provide the sender, and if that's a `FrameworkElement`, you should be able to cast that and get a listbox object. From there, you can examine the `DataContext` property and cast that to whatever your binding class is.

An alternative design is to subclass the ListBox component and add your own property to express the binding source in a way that would be most useful to you. That way, you'd have access to that property in your generic event handler and you wouldn't have to worry about trying to use reflection, or other methods, to figure out what the binding source object is...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately the cast portion is where the issue is, as it's a generic event handler for all the listboxes it doesn't know which BindingClass it should use as each listbox had a different binding Property. What I don't really want is an event per listbox as they all need the same function, just a different binding Property.

Comment: You can cast to object and then use the ListBox name in a switch statement to figure out which Binding Source you want to reference; also, listbox.DataContext.GetType().ToString() might help you determine the class of the data context you had used when you configured that listbox object instance.

Answer (score 0):

How can i obtain the bound source Property (reference) so i can remove an underlying value?

`box.ItemsSource` does give you a reference to the source collection. But since the type of the `ItemsSource` property is `IEnumerable`, you need to cast the value to something that supports the removal of items before you will be able to remove any item. The `ICollection<T>` interface should work. It's implemented by both `List<T>` and `ObservableCollection<T>` for example.

```
var x = box.ItemsSource as ICollection<string>;
if (x != null)
    x.Remove("...");
```